# Fenchel duality in conic program

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems, dual-cone

The question is from the textbook `Convex Optimization Algorithms, prof. Bertsekas, p.511`

A special case of Fenchel duality is the following:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&{\text{min}}
& & f(x)\\
& \text{s.t.} & &  x \in \mathcal{C}\\ 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where
1. $f: \mathbb{R^n} \mapsto (-\infty,\infty]$ is closed, proper, convex.
2. $\mathcal{C}$ is a closed, convex cone in $\mathbb{R^n}$

The dual problem is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&{\text{min}}
& & f^*(\lambda)\\
& \text{s.t.} & &  \lambda \in \mathcal{\hat C}\\ 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where
1. $f^*$ is the conjugate of $f$
2. $\mathcal{\hat C}$ is the dual cone

My question is:   **Why the dual problem is a conjugate function rather than 
the minimization of a Lagrange dual function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the lagrangian $g(y)=\inf_{x\epsilon C} ( f(x))$. 
The dual cone is the set $C^*=\{y: y^Tx \geq 0 ,\forall x \epsilon C\}$. 
Then $g(y)=\inf_{x\epsilon C} ( f(x)+y^Tx)$ where $y\epsilon C^*$, since $y^Tx\geq 0$. This is equal to $g(y)=-\sup_{x\epsilon C} (-f(x)-y^Tx)=-\sup_{x\epsilon C} ((-y)^Tx-f(x))=-f^*(-y)$. The last equality comes from definition of conjugate function.
So we have $\max_{y} g(y)=\min_{y \epsilon C^*} f^*(-y)$. You can see that lagrangian is completely related to conjugate function.

Comment: The first line tells strong duality holds and definition of dual cone, both of which are ok. The second line $g(y)$ is the definition of conjugate function? shoud it be $sup(y^Tx-f(x))$?

Comment: I simply add a positive term $y^Tx$ to $f(x)$. So the value of the $inf$ doesn't change.

Comment: I mean how to say "Then $g(y)=\inf_{x\epsilon C} ( f(x)+y^Tx)$"

Comment: Maybe I know. To form the dual problem, the constraint $x\in C$ is through its dual cone.